# How to recieve streamed audio with Chromium in Lubuntu?

Tags: sound, lubuntu, chromium, mplayer

Running Lubuntu 13.04 fresh install.

Default chromium install fails on `pls` or `m3u` streaming audio, after attempting to install the plugin, due to following error:

```
could not load mplayerplug-in is now gecko-mediaplayer 1.0.8.
```

---

Update : 2013-11

Using Chromium Version 30.0.1599.114 Ubuntu 13.04 (30.0.1599.114-0ubuntu0.13.04.2)

See plugins at chrome://plugins/ 
( According to https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142064?hl=en )

All of these plugins are listed using "Gecko Media Player 1.0.8" in chrome://plugins/

- RealPlayer 9
- DivX Browser Plug-In
- QuickTime Plug-in 7.6.9
- Windows Media Player Plug-in

Including the oddly named

- mplayerplug-in is now gecko-mediaplayer 1.0.8

---

I also tried installing the VLC as @qdoe suggested , but received the following error.  `Could not load VLC Web Plugin.`

This now smells like a local plugin config issue if VLC is showing the same error.

---

Answer (score 1):

It's a [bug reported here](http://code.google.com/p/gecko-mediaplayer/issues/detail?id=180) with firefox plugin **gecko-mediaplayer** ported to chromium. The issue is still open and the developers seem a bit clueless.

A workaround would be to install another plugin, for example vlc which is also a very simple but good media player and has a browser plugin.

```
$ sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```

- Ubuntu package description: http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/browser-plugin-vlc
- VLC official homepage: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/

Give it a try until gecko-mediaplayer is fixed.

Comment: Thanks , I commented on the bug, and updated the question.  VLC returned a similar error, and I wonder if this is somehow a local config issue.